# Magento 2.3 Extremely Slow - Multiple PHP Processes

Tags: magento2, migration, slowbackend

As to replicate pretty much as the poster in this thread -
[Magento 2.2 often extremely slow, 100% processor usage after setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198084/magento-2-2-often-extremely-slow-100-processor-usage-after-setupupgrade/259988?noredirect=1#comment366456_259988)

I have now had to restore a **Magento** from overnight backup 3 times now. I am working to move to **Magento 2.3** from **Magento 1.9** but I get as far as **installing few extensions** and then suddenly Magento will start to slow and spawn loads of PHP processes and send the server load sky high. I went as far as removing every single extension I added that day and still the same. **Restore database backup** too, same issue. I cannot find a way without having to restore from a backup or a fresh install every time. I don't ever see how I will be able to run this in **production environment** if it keeps doing this...

I don't understand why it randomly does this.... I'm not an expert. I have ran every possible command and searched heavily for a fix for this issue to no avail.

Comment: were you on a developer mode ?

Comment: please check app/etc/env.php 'MAGE_MODE' => 'default' or 'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',

Comment: It made no difference which mode I was in.

Comment: but in which mode are you now?

Comment: that's kind of weird, because if you are on a default mode you can leave all cache open and your problem will be gone

Comment: I'm currently restoring a backup from last night to get back on track. I didn't expect such quick responses, so thank you. I am going to repeat extensions I was installing and if the issue arises again (as it seems to consistently) I will let you know.

Comment: Backup restored, started installing extensions again, not even same as before. Sites back to doing the same again... try and load it yourself. queenbees.co.uk youl be waiting 5 to 10 minutes.

Comment: Pid Owner Priority CPU % Memory % Command
38631 (Trace) (Kill) queenbees 0   42.36   3.95 php-fpm: pool queenbees_co_uk
38642 (Trace) (Kill) queenbees 0   41.94   2.99 php-fpm: pool queenbees_co_uk
38463 (Trace) (Kill) queenbees 0   40.98   2.77 php-fpm: pool queenbees_co_uk
38944 (Trace) (Kill) queenbees 0   31.95   2.02 php-fpm: pool queenbees_co_uk
38941 (Trace) (Kill) queenbees 0   31.46   2.04 php-fpm: pool queenbees_co_uk

Comment: Further to this I so far identified that as in the previous post mentioned, composer was disabling cache.

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this as I'm having what seems to be the same issue?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151676)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151676)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple resources available to improve Magento 2 performance and all of them are pretty well documented.

Mode: Magento 2 has introduced modes, being the default one the slowest. Give the developer mode a try and always run your live store in production mode. More info [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for speeding up your Magento site. However, the very first thing that you should do is running the developer mode.

You can also try using Varnish Cache. Follow these steps:

1. [Install](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-install.html) and [configure](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-configure.html) Varnish Cache.
2. Head to **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page
   Cache**.
3. Select **Varnish Cache** in **Caching Application**.

In addition, you can try activating CSS/JS minification and enabling flat categories and products. You can find the steps [right here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259990/magento-2-3-extremely-slow-multiple-php-processes).

Answer (score 0):

Slow magento 2 is not because of installing new modules. Magento 2 is much heavier than magento 1.9. So you need to optimize it and do some process to speed up.

- Disable useless extensions

  php bin/magento module:disable VendorName_PluginName

to re-enable it

```
php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_PluginName
```

- Choose the fastest hosting that you can afford
- Turn on cache
- Turn on Production mode

  php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
- Never Use JS Bundling in:

> You can double check JS bundling is off by going to backend menu
>   Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer:

- Enable CSS/JS Minification
- Use Built-in Cache or Varnish

Comment: We are talking up to 5 - 10 minutes to load a single page. I have just restored a backup and Magento runs perfectly fine, a single php process as expected. This does not explain the multiple processes it keeps running.

Comment: Try newrelic, I had used it in my website, it describe you the piece of code where your queries taking time. And its free for 15 days, its a builtin feature of magento 2, you just need to register on newrelic and integrate on your website

Answer (score 0):

Do you know much about your server setup? I've seen this happen on servers configured to use php-fpm and essentially there aren't enough workers configured.

This is the best explanation I can find.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535926/how-php-fpm-manages-workers-with-dynamic-process-manager

Or maybe this

https://serverfault.com/questions/645755/differences-and-dis-advanages-between-fast-cgi-cgi-mod-php-suphp-php-fpm